# Firebase Messaging not sending notification when push notification authentication request is delayed

Tags: firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I updated my Firebase to 4.2 and FirebaseMessaging to 2.0.3, then my push notifications code no longer working.

So I tried the quickstart project, and found out that if I request the push notification at later time, the token is not working even though it seemed like it was generated properly. (Sent the token to FCM and getting a success message, but the push never came through to the device).

The Firebase quickstart repo is: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/messaging/MessagingExample/AppDelegate.m

Then I added delay to the request for push notification from the user by 10 seconds:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 10 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    // Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
    // show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) {
        // iOS 7.1 or earlier. Disable the deprecation warnings.
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
        UIRemoteNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
        (UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge);
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:allNotificationTypes];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
    } else {
        // iOS 8 or later
        // [START register_for_notifications]
        if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max) {
            UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
            (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
            UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
            [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        } else {
            // iOS 10 or later
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
            UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
            UNAuthorizationOptionAlert
            | UNAuthorizationOptionSound
            | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
            [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            }];
#endif
        }

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
        // [END register_for_notifications]
    }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is an issue with 2.0.3 build.
They suggested to downgrade FirebaseInstanceID to 2.0.0

pod 'FirebaseInstanceID', '2.0.0'

Reference:
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/327#issuecomment-332655731

Hope this helps someone!